# c# WCF deserialize issue

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

Having class library which consists of below classes and shared by both ServerSide(WCF) and ClientSide(Windows Application) application:

```
[DataContract]
public class A
{
    public A()
    {

    }

    [DataMemeber]
    public int A1 { get; set; }

    [DataMemeber]
    public string A2 { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class B
{
    public B()
    {

    }

    [DataMemeber]
    public int B1 { get; set; }

    [DataMemeber]
    public string B2 { get; set; }

    [DataContract]
    public A B_A { get; set; }
}
```

If I request only object of Class B, it return errors because Property B_A is NULL (in fact Property B_A is NOT NULL at ServerSide) and it cannot deserialize at Client side. Confusion is that, I think WCF should take care of that, like if there is any other objects needs, it will automatically serialize also. Any ideas pls?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You should mark fields with `DataMember`

So this:

```
[DataContract]
public A B_A { get; set; }
```

should be:

```
[DataMember]
public A B_A { get; set; }
```

Comment: sorry, it was mistyping, it is marked as DataMember

Comment: @Tim, actually it should work, mb some dependencies or your class contains exception inside f.e., share real code